# PHP file_get_contents between two server

Tags: php, http

I am trying to send a variable from a client who runs xampp with a static IP to my server (domain) and back using `file_get_contents`.

How can we do this without opening port on client site?

`client(xampp)->Server(domain)->Cleint`

My code works fine when I open port 80 on the client computer but I do not want to do this for every computer.

Comment: I don't think you can do it any other way. Port 80 is the TCP port used for making HTTP requests. As long as you are making web requests, I don't think you have a choice but to open the port.

Comment: There is no other way of communication with client computer, so how do other software activate license over internet

Comment: With a web request. TCP or UDP..

Comment: let me try that I put the result up